# Why do only some elements update in Ionic view? And only for some devices?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

in my Ionic3 web app I have the html page that is something like that:

```
<h1> {{question}} </h1>

<ion-list formControlName="content" radio-group [(ngModel)]="value">
  <li *ngFor="let answer of question.answers">          
    <ion-item text-wrap>
      <ion-label> {{answer.text}} </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </li>
</ion-list>
```

Only on some devices (some PCs, some phones, I don't get the similarities among them), when I change the object named question to another object (the next one in the array that contains all the questions in the test), the answers get updated (in the ion-label inside the list) but the question doesn't change.

In other devices everything works perfectly.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand what you want. But one thing i notice that you are printing 'question' object in h1 tag. Which i think may not printing readable value. Use json pipe to print object. example <h1>{{question | json}}. I know this is not the answer of your question but may this will help you.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I try to explain better. If question number 1 is "How old are you?" and the three answers are "18", "25", "30", when I click on next, it is supposed to go on question number 2. The question should become "What's your name?" and the answers should become "John","Max","Luke". It happens that the answers are updated with the new ones, but the question is not, and remains the old one

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue is related with the authomatic translation of Google Chrome (all the devices that had the problem have the autotranslation enabled). Disabling it, it works